# Delete a word from a file in c

Tags: c, string, file

I have found this code in the answers before but when i apply this code it deletes also the first character of the first word. This happens everytime that I apply the code. I don't know where is the problem. I want to delete a specific word, but not the first character of the first word. Can anyone help me ?!
P.s Sorry for my bad english :)

```
/*
 * C Program Delete a specific Line from a Text File
 */
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fileptr1, *fileptr2;
    char filename[40];
    char ch;
    int delete_line, temp = 1;

    printf("Enter file name: ");
    scanf("%s", filename);

    //open file in read mode
    fileptr1 = fopen(filename, "r");
    ch = getc(fileptr1);
    while (ch != EOF)
    {
    printf("%c", ch);
    ch = getc(fileptr1);
   }

   //rewind
   rewind(fileptr1);
   printf(" \n Enter line number of the line to be deleted:");
   scanf("%d", &delete_line);

   //open new file in write mode
   fileptr2 = fopen("replica.c", "w");
   ch = getc(fileptr1);
    while (ch != EOF)
    {
    ch = getc(fileptr1);
        if (ch == '\n')
        temp++;
        //except the line to be deleted
        if (temp != delete_line)
        {
            //copy all lines in file replica.c
            putc(ch, fileptr2);
        }
   }
   fclose(fileptr1);
   fclose(fileptr2);
   remove(filename);

   //rename the file replica.c to original name
   rename("replica.c", filename);
   printf("\n The contents of file after being modified are as follows:\n");
   fileptr1 = fopen(filename, "r");
   ch = getc(fileptr1);
   while (ch != EOF)
   {
     printf("%c", ch);
     ch = getc(fileptr1);
   }
     fclose(fileptr1);
     return 0;
```

}

Comment: I changed it to int but it keeps deleting the first character.

Comment: This code is not a program to delete the specified word.

Comment: I delete it by number of the line I want to delete

Comment: You cannot "delete a Word from a file" unless it is the last characters in the file. Copy the file **except** for what you want to "delete" instead. (That's what the code does, btw.). And we are not a debugging service for code you found somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are ignoring the first time that you get a character when writing your file:

```
fileptr2 = fopen("replica.c", "w");
ch = getc(fileptr1); //<--- This is the problem; you are never writing this one
while (ch != EOF)
{
    ch = getc(fileptr1); //<--- This one is overwriting it
```

The simple solution would be to put the `ch = getc(fileptr1);` at the end of the while-loop instead of using it at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

```
//open new file in write mode
fileptr2 = fopen("replica.c", "w");
ch = getc(fileptr1);
while (ch != EOF)
{
ch = getc(fileptr1);
```

In this part you have the problem, you read the first character and without writing in the output file you read again.

Comment: Yes brother. Thank you very much. I understand that :)))))